# ListSelection Listener not firing event

Tags: java, swing

does anyone know why
System.out.println(e.getFirstIndex());
System.out.println(e.getLastIndex());
 both does nothing? is my Listener not registered properly? i am trying to know when a certain cell is selected and do something to it. Like setting a default text for that cell when it is selected either by mouse or key.

```
package VLGui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.*;

import VLCore.cellSelectedListener;


public class mainFrame extends JFrame{

    private JLabel lblTime;
    private Vector columnName = new Vector();
    private Vector tblData = new Vector();
    private JTable JTbl;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000,new MyListener());

    private JPanel topPnl,cenPnl,btmPnl;
    private Calendar time;

    private Object[] columnNames = {"Veh No.","Description","Time In","Time Out"};

    public mainFrame()
    {
        timer.start();
        //jtable settings
        JTbl = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames,1));
        JTbl.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(JTbl.getPreferredSize());
        JTbl.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        JTbl.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
        JTbl.setColumnSelectionInterval(0,0);
        JTbl.setRowSelectionInterval(0,0);
        JTbl.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new cellSelectedListener(JTbl));
        //Settings
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Vehicle Log");
        setSize(500,1000);
        setVisible(true);

        //Dec
        JScrollPane tableContainer = new JScrollPane(JTbl);
        topPnl = new JPanel();
        cenPnl = new JPanel();
        btmPnl = new JPanel();
        lblTime = new JLabel();


        //Adding Components
        topPnl.add(lblTime,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cenPnl.add(tableContainer);


        getContentPane().add(topPnl,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(cenPnl,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //add(btmPnl);

    }

    public class MyListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            time = Calendar.getInstance();
            lblTime.setText(time.getTime().toString());
            lblTime.repaint();
        }

    }
}




package VLCore;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class cellSelectedListener implements ListSelectionListener {
private JTable jTbl;

    public cellSelectedListener()
    {

    }

    public cellSelectedListener(JTable tbl)
    {
        jTbl = tbl;
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel)e.getSource();
        System.out.println(e.getFirstIndex());
        System.out.println(e.getLastIndex());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the row is already selected.

The tables selection model relates to the selection changes of the rows.

If you change the order in which you register the listener as follows...

```
JTbl.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new cellSelectedListener(JTbl));
JTbl.setColumnSelectionInterval(0, 0);
JTbl.setRowSelectionInterval(0, 0);
```

You will see the row selection change.

**Update code review...**

Generally, this `JTbl.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(JTbl.getPreferredSize());` is not a good idea.  You really want to leave it up to the scroll pane to make these kind of decisions.  You can alter the column sizes if you really want to effect the width of the table.

Java naming conventions suggest that all instance variables start with a lower case character, so`JTbl` would become `jTbl` and all classes start with an upper case, so `mainFrame` would become `MainFrame`...small thing, but it's what people are really use to.

Comment: Nice catch.  Deleted my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: @MelNicholson Took a little digging and WTF? ;)

Comment: Yep. The problem I found was not the one the question was about.